# Add a one-to-many connection to Many-to-Many

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, post, asp.net-identity

I have a Many To Many relationship with some additional fields. But as there are Photos added to the many to many relationship which might apply to other relations I wanted to seperate it so I can change it by just altering the One to many relation. This is the model

```
public class Segment
{
    public int SegmentId { get; set; }
    public int ConnectionPointIdEnd { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionName { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionInformation { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Direction { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ConnectionPointRoute> ConnectionPointRoutes { get; set; }
}
public class ConnectionPointRoute
{
    public int ConnectionPointId { get; set; }
    public int RouteId { get; set; }
    public int SegmentId { get; set; }
    public  int Position { get; set; }
    public ConnectionPoint ConnectionPoint { get; set; }
    public Route Route { get; set; }
    public Segment Segment { get; set; }
}
```

And the modelbuilder looks like this :

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ConnectionPointRoute>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.ConnectionPointId, c.RouteId, c.SegmentId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ConnectionPoint>()
            .HasMany(c => c.ConnectionPointRoutes)
            .WithRequired(x => x.ConnectionPoint)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ConnectionPointId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Route>()
            .HasMany(c => c.ConnectionPointRoutes)
            .WithRequired(x => x.Route)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.RouteId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Segment>()
            .HasMany(c => c.ConnectionPointRoutes)
            .WithRequired(x => x.Segment)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.SegmentId);
    }
```

And this all works well for getting the items, but for some reason it doesn't allow me to post a new Route for instance, it gets me the error:

> "Multiplicity constraint violated. The role
>   'Segment_ConnectionPointRoutes_Source' of the relationship
>   'InBuildingNavigator.Data.Models.Segment_ConnectionPointRoutes' has
>   multiplicity 1 or 0..1."

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this! I had an error in my Post code, I added the full child objects which doesn't make a whole lot of sense in my case.

Ask me if you want a more detailed fix!

Answer (score 0):

Just two more things to this:

1. I would recommend you to use an extra object for the many-to-many relationship (if you don't already do this). This will give you more control over the table name and over selections you may want to do.
2. use the virtual keyword for your properties, which you do not need directly (for your collections) - this will allow ef to implement lazy loading on them.

Comment: I chose to use explicit loading, as I want to have close control over the data. I must say that I can't really follow your first suggestion, care to explain?

Comment: It's from my own experiences. For example: I had a user has friends relation - a classic many-to-many relation. This relation has another property, which is friendStatus (is friendship acknowledged). When I wanted to get all acknowledged friends, this tended to be difficult when working with asp.net identity. Don't misunderstand me, the automatic ef way to do many-to-many works well, I just have experienced it tends to get difficult to customize later.